# Why is $\{\omega \in \Omega:t\rightarrow X_t(\omega) \text{ is continuous on } [0,T]\}$ $\mathcal{F}_T^X$-measurable for a cadlag process?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I'm try to solving the following exercise:

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a real valued stochastic process such that, for all $\omega\in \Omega$ the map $t\rightarrow X_t(\omega)$ is right continuous and for every $t>0$ the left limit

$$\lim_{s\uparrow t}X_s (\omega)$$
exists. Consider the set, for $T>0$

$$C=\{\omega \in \Omega:t\rightarrow X_t(\omega) \text{ is continuous on }  [0,T]\}$$
Show that it belongs to
$$\mathcal{F}_T^X:=\sigma(X_t:t\in[0,T]).$$

I know that we have a clear solution in ([Show that a certain set is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112477/show-that-a-certain-set-is-measurable)) but can someone help me to keep going with this solution:

From right continuity we have

$C=\{\omega \in \Omega:\lim_{s\uparrow t}X_s (\omega)=X_t(\omega) ,\forall t\in[0,T]\}=\bigcap_{t\in[0,T]}\{\omega \in \Omega:\lim_{s\uparrow t}X_s (\omega)=X_t(\omega)\}$

now I want to have in the last equality a countable intersection but I'm not able to do that. I know that for a cadlag process holds that the set of discontinuity points is a countable set but in my opinion this set could depend from the choice of $\omega$ and so I don't know how to conclude.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that a certain set is measurable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112477/show-that-a-certain-set-is-measurable)

Comment: thanks for the solution. So my approach, that is completely different from the solution is wrong or not??

Comment: In the solution you say that a right continuous function $f$ is 
 uniformly continuous on $[0,t]$ if and only if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,t]$. Why does it hold?

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76854/extending-a-function-by-continuity-from-a-dense-subset-of-a-space

Comment: but if I take a function like that: $f(x)=1$ if $x<\sqrt{2}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\geq \sqrt{2}$ for $x\in [0,2]$ f is $cadlag$, continous in $\mathbb{Q}$, but not in $[0,2]$

Comment: The function $f$ in your comment is not *uniformly* continuous.

Comment: Oh sorry, now I understand where was my mistake. Do you have any suggestion for my first question?